# Is there an equivalent to Response.Redirect("~/Controller/") in Asp.Net Core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Is there an equivalent to `Response.Redirect("~/Controller/")` in `Asp.Net Core 2` ?

I don't want to use `ViewComponent`. Instead of, I want call a Controller and an action method from a view.

```
@using Jahan.Blog.Web.Mvc.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<header>
    <h1> Blog </h1>
</header>
<div class="blog-description">
    <p>...</p>
</div>

@{ Response.Redirect("~/Article/");}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this if within the controller method:

```
RedirectToAction("yourActionName", "YourControllerName");
```

or:

```
Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName");
```

This can also be used with parameters as defined in your AppStart -> RouteConfig.cs file

```
i.e  
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "YourControllerName", action = "YourActionName", id = 
          UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

to pass parameters simply add new keyword for get method

```
Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName", new { id = id });
```

for Post Method use

```
Url.Action("YourActionName", "YourControllerName", new { "your variable" = id });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return a  result from your action.

Views should not contain logic like that; you should move all such logic to an action or filter.

Answer (score -1):

You are redirecting from the view... a view in [ASP MVC Core 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view) or [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio) do not have access to the context of the request, so they cant redirect...